# Configuring locations of web resources when packing to WAR for Apache Tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, tomcat

I am trying to deploy my web application to Apache Tomcat without using the embedded server in Spring Boot. I've followed all the steps found in guides and successfully deployed the application (by that I mean it's found in the Tomcat manager), but when I go to the webapp url I get a 404.

The problem is that my HTML files are located in webapps/mywebapp/WEB-INF/classes. 
When I move the HTML files to simply webapps/mywebapp the page successfully loads, but without the resources such as my javascript files or image files. When running the app using the spring boot embedded server the webapp works just fine. Here is my project structure :

[image]

My pom.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>io.johnnathan.springboot</groupId>
    <artifactId>product-store</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>

    <name>product-store</name>
    <description>Product storefront using Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.3</version>

        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1</version>

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>8.0.12</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version><!--$NO-MVN-MAN-VER$-->

        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

File structure of unpacked WAR file when deployed via Apache Tomcat (contained within product-store (mywebapp) folder :

```
+---META-INF
|   |   MANIFEST.MF
|   |   war-tracker
|   |
|   \---maven
|       \---io.johnnathan.springboot
|           \---product-store
|                   pom.properties
|                   pom.xml
|
+---org
|   \---springframework
|       \---boot
|           \---loader
|               |   ExecutableArchiveLauncher.class
|               |   JarLauncher.class
|               |   LaunchedURLClassLoader$UseFastConnectionExceptionsEnumeration.class
|               |   LaunchedURLClassLoader.class
|               |   Launcher.class
|               |   MainMethodRunner.class
|               |   PropertiesLauncher$1.class
|               |   PropertiesLauncher$ArchiveEntryFilter.class
|               |   PropertiesLauncher$PrefixMatchingArchiveFilter.class
|               |   PropertiesLauncher.class
|               |   WarLauncher.class
|               |
|               +---archive
|               |       Archive$Entry.class
|               |       Archive$EntryFilter.class
|               |       Archive.class
|               |       ExplodedArchive$1.class
|               |       ExplodedArchive$FileEntry.class
|               |       ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator$EntryComparator.class
|               |       ExplodedArchive$FileEntryIterator.class
|               |       ExplodedArchive.class
|               |       JarFileArchive$EntryIterator.class
|               |       JarFileArchive$JarFileEntry.class
|               |       JarFileArchive.class
|               |
|               +---data
|               |       RandomAccessData.class
|               |       RandomAccessDataFile$1.class
|               |       RandomAccessDataFile$DataInputStream.class
|               |       RandomAccessDataFile$FileAccess.class
|               |       RandomAccessDataFile.class
|               |
|               +---jar
|               |       AsciiBytes.class
|               |       Bytes.class
|               |       CentralDirectoryEndRecord.class
|               |       CentralDirectoryFileHeader.class
|               |       CentralDirectoryParser.class
|               |       CentralDirectoryVisitor.class
|               |       FileHeader.class
|               |       Handler.class
|               |       JarEntry.class
|               |       JarEntryFilter.class
|               |       JarFile$1.class
|               |       JarFile$2.class
|               |       JarFile$JarFileType.class
|               |       JarFile.class
|               |       JarFileEntries$1.class
|               |       JarFileEntries$EntryIterator.class
|               |       JarFileEntries.class
|               |       JarURLConnection$1.class
|               |       JarURLConnection$JarEntryName.class
|               |       JarURLConnection.class
|               |       StringSequence.class
|               |       ZipInflaterInputStream.class
|               |
|               \---util
|                       SystemPropertyUtils.class
|
\---WEB-INF
    +---classes
    |   |   application.properties
    |   |
    |   +---io
    |   |   \---johnnathan
    |   |       \---springboot
    |   |           |   ProductStoreApp.class
    |   |           |
    |   |           +---index
    |   |           |       IndexController.class
    |   |           |
    |   |           \---product
    |   |                   Product.class
    |   |                   ProductController.class
    |   |                   ProductDAO$1.class
    |   |                   ProductDAO$ProductRowMapper.class
    |   |                   ProductDAO.class
    |   |                   ProductService.class
    |   |
    |   +---static
    |   |   +---css
    |   |   |       bootstrap.min.css
    |   |   |       custom.css
    |   |   |
    |   |   +---images
    |   |   |   |   lights.jpg
    |   |   |   |   mountain.jpg
    |   |   |   |
    |   |   |   \---svg
    |   |   |           house-with-wifi-svgrepo-com.svg
    |   |   |
    |   |   \---js
    |   |           addProduct.js
    |   |           bootstrap.min.js
    |   |           custom.js
    |   |           jquery-3.3.1.js
    |   |
    |   \---templates
    |           addProduct.html
    |           index.html
    |           productPage.html
    |           products.html
    |
    +---lib
    |       accessors-smart-1.2.jar
    |       android-json-0.0.20131108.vaadin1.jar
    |       asm-5.0.4.jar
    |       assertj-core-3.9.1.jar
    |       attoparser-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       bootstrap-4.1.3.jar
    |       byte-buddy-1.7.11.jar
    |       byte-buddy-agent-1.7.11.jar
    |       hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
    |       hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
    |       HikariCP-2.7.9.jar
    |       javax.annotation-api-1.3.2.jar
    |       jquery-3.3.1.jar
    |       json-path-2.4.0.jar
    |       json-smart-2.3.jar
    |       jsonassert-1.5.0.jar
    |       jul-to-slf4j-1.7.25.jar
    |       junit-4.12.jar
    |       log4j-api-2.10.0.jar
    |       log4j-to-slf4j-2.10.0.jar
    |       logback-classic-1.2.3.jar
    |       logback-core-1.2.3.jar
    |       mockito-core-2.15.0.jar
    |       mysql-connector-java-8.0.12.jar
    |       objenesis-2.6.jar
    |       popper.js-1.14.3.jar
    |       protobuf-java-2.6.0.jar
    |       slf4j-api-1.7.25.jar
    |       snakeyaml-1.19.jar
    |       spring-aop-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-beans-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-starter-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-starter-jdbc-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-starter-logging-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-starter-test-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-test-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-context-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-core-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-expression-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-jcl-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-jdbc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-test-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       spring-tx-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
    |       thymeleaf-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar
    |       thymeleaf-extras-java8time-3.0.1.RELEASE.jar
    |       thymeleaf-spring5-3.0.9.RELEASE.jar
    |       unbescape-1.1.5.RELEASE.jar
    |       xmlunit-core-2.5.1.jar
    |
    \---lib-provided
            classmate-1.3.4.jar
            hibernate-validator-6.0.11.Final.jar
            jackson-annotations-2.9.0.jar
            jackson-core-2.9.6.jar
            jackson-databind-2.9.6.jar
            jackson-datatype-jdk8-2.9.6.jar
            jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.9.6.jar
            jackson-module-parameter-names-2.9.6.jar
            javafx.base-11.0.0-SNAPSHOT-linux.jar
            javafx.base-11.0.0-SNAPSHOT-mac.jar
            javafx.base-11.0.0-SNAPSHOT-win.jar
            javafx.base-11.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
            jboss-logging-3.3.2.Final.jar
            spring-boot-starter-json-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
            spring-boot-starter-tomcat-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
            spring-boot-starter-web-2.0.4.RELEASE.jar
            spring-web-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
            spring-webmvc-5.0.8.RELEASE.jar
            tomcat-embed-core-8.5.32.jar
            tomcat-embed-el-8.5.32.jar
            tomcat-embed-websocket-8.5.32.jar
            validation-api-2.0.1.Final.jar
```

Do I have to move all my web resources to a different file structure? If so, what is the proper file structure when deploying as WAR?

Comment: Which URL do you try to access? What is the context path of your app?

Comment: @JBNizet I am trying to access "localhost:8080/product-store/products". I have a controller class that maps /products to products.html. I have not set the context path for my app, because it worked just fine when running on the embedded server. To what should I set my context path given my file structure?

Comment: Never mind! Got it to work. Problem was with my dependencies in pom.xml. Answer provided below.

Answer (score 0):

Problem was with my pom.xml.

The dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

comes with the embedded server, so I set the scope as "provided". However there are other things needed in this dependency required to deploy as WAR properly. So I changed this dependency to :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```